# Oracle object type

Tags: database, oracle, types

If we are just creating type without specifying  clause as shown below then by default it will create type with which datatype i.e. varchar or number

```
CREATE TYPE <TYP_NAME>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an [Incomplete Type](http://www.remote-dba.net/t_grid_rac_incomplete_type.htm).

> An incomplete type would be used where
>   a type references a second type that
>   references the first type (a circular
>   reference such as emp-supervisor).
>   This allows the incomplete type to be
>   referenced before it is completed.
>   However, before a table can be
>   constructed from an incomplete type,
>   it must be completed.